# Unable to subtract datetime64 using DataFrame.eval()

Tags: python, pandas, numexpr

Given a DataFrame with a couple of timestamps:

```
In [88]: df.dtypes
Out[88]:
Time             datetime64[ns]
uniqstime        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

If I call `eval()`, I get a type error:

```
In [91]: df.eval('since = Time - uniqstime')
...

ValueError: unkown type timedelta64[ns]
```

(By the way, "unknown" is misspelled in the error message.)

But I can use Python notation:

```
In [92]: df['since'] = df.Time - df.uniqstime
```

Is there an issue with assigning a `timedelta` in numexpr?

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5007 - unsupported at this time. unless a lot of interest in it (these are done in python space anyhow, so no real advantage to using eval here).

Comment: @Jeff If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The unknown misspelling is from numexpr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already was issue on github (albeit closed), see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5007

It is unsupported at this time.  However, their is no real advantage ATM as these computations are done in python space anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're interested in just making your code shorter and more readable (a laudable goal), then `numexpr` would have to support `timedelta64` operations for this to have a performance benefit. As @Jeff says, these (and `datetime64` operations) are evaluated in Python space because `numexpr` doesn't support `pandas` `NaT` (`N`ot-`a`-`T`ime). However, non-`timedelta64` ops *are* evaluated using `numexpr` so you'd probably have to have a really huge `timedelta64` array for it to create a bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah, code readability was really the goal here. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As of pandas `0.23`, you can do that by setting the `engine` parameter to `python`, eg.:

```
df.eval('since = Time - uniqstime', engine='python')
```

From the pandas [documentation of `pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
engine : string or None, default 'numexpr', {'python', 'numexpr'}
    The engine used to evaluate the expression. Supported engines are
    - None         : tries to use ``numexpr``, falls back to ``python``
    - ``'numexpr'``: This default engine evaluates pandas objects using
                     numexpr for large speed ups in complex expressions
                     with large frames.
    - ``'python'``: Performs operations as if you had ``eval``'d in top
                    level python. This engine is generally not that useful.
    More backends may be available in the future.
```

I disagree with the statement that it is 'not that useful'. In my opinion, it can shorten the code necessary to do some operations and sometimes it may come in handy.